# Quiero agregar codigo js a una pagina

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando agregar elemento **javascript** a mi pagina web, pero la cosa es que no quiero agregarlo en el código **html**, quiero agregarlo así mismo desde *javascript*.

Había intentado algo como `document.write`,
 pero esto me reemplaza la pagina completa entonces lo que quiero es agregar esto `<script https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=" + API_KEY/>`

Comment: has probado a insertar la dependencia javascript con el tag <script> en el head del html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si usas **jQuery** podrías hacerlo así:

```
$.getScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY');
```

En este caso puedes llamar a una función callback cuando termina:

```
$.getScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY', function() {
    // hacer algo cuando se ha cargado la librería
});
```

Con **JavaScript** podrías hacerlo así:

```
var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
scriptTag.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY';
document.body.appendChild(scriptTag);
```

Comment: gracias por el comentario voy a intentarlo